# Update from 12.10 failed

Tags: updates

A while back I was trying to update from 12.10 and my roommate unpluged my laptop and ever since then I have not been able to open software updater or start up disk creator. It does not give an error message but it won't open. What can I do to solve this problem?

```
sudo apt-get update                                  
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
sudo apt-get upgrade
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

Comment: Open a terminal (CTRL + ALT + T) and enter `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`. Paste the output of that command into your question.

Comment: ok so i ran sudo dpkg --configure -a and now it will run all the way through 'sudo apt-get update' but i still can't ubdate.

Comment: OK the `dpkg` warning was expected, and you have managed to clean up the mess from the interrupted update. You say you can't update. What happens if you try `sudo apt-get upgrade`?

Comment: @Jos this shouldn't work on an unsupported release. Ubuntu 12.10 is unsupported since May 16, 2014.

Comment: @user300458 Ah yes, you are correct.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/91815/300458

Answer (score 1):

When you interrupt the package manager a couple of things can happen..

- it could have been stopped while either installing/configuring a package
- left the lock on the upgrade process so you can't run two upgrades at once.

In a general sense, exit any package managers (synaptic, software center) and issur the following from a terminal prompt.

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```